# How to implement Webrtc real time video filters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webrtc, html5-video

I'm using nodejs and reactjs for video calls using Webrtc ,I want to know how to implement real time filters during video calls ,like In snapchat.
I want to know, what I should be looking for in order to achieve that

Comment: ... I'm a bit unfamiliar with Webrtc (do you have a repo I can look at?), but generally - filters are just functions you run on data. gaussian blur for example has a relatively simple algorithm... but if you are talking about filters that follow faces... maybe tensorflow.js? pretty sure that's achieved with machine learning.